# Trying to get certain numbers and put them each on their own line

Tags: ruby, regex

all the numbers inside the le that could be days in a month|
1-31. Assume that numbers 1-9 may or may not be preceded by a 0. The one or two digits of the numbers must be sandwiched by non-numeric characters. Print each matching number on its
own line.

So basically I read all the numbers 1-31 or 01-31 and output them on their own line.

What I know is that 
I can use a split to maybe split this up and that would be good and I also know i could use something similar to `([1-9]|0[0-9]|1[1-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])` to find the numbers, but after that I'm stumped and could use some help.

Edit: to answer some questions this is in ruby and some test input / output here to help
Input-

```
1
10
12
18 19 20
21 22 ----asdfadsf 23t24####25,26,27,
28!
29.
30
31
32
33
01 02 03x04x05x06x07x08x09
001
002
1x1a
    35


-87 76 101 10057

-13 -1.5
```

Output- 1
10
12
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
1
1
13
1
5
(each one of those on it's own line, but I didn't want to make it too long) I also removed a few to make it a smaller file so there is a chance i missed removing a number in the output, but I think I got them all.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: What is some sample data we can use? Are characters in the string? What is the format of your file?

Comment: here was the input...http://pastebin.com/E8KNEJLx
here is the ouput... http://pastebin.com/dGemznGC

Comment: `ruby` should be added as a tag, and the sample input and output should be included here instead of somewhere off-site. (If the off-site location is unavailable, the content is not available for future readers who find this in a search result.) Please edit your question and include the information. (If the input is large, post just enough of it to make your question clear.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll do it for you assuming your numbers are a single string `x`

```
x.split(/\D+/).select {|n| n.to_i >= 0 && n.to_i < 32 && n.length < 3}.join("\n")
```

If they are in a file, you can easily convert them to a string using `IO::read(path)`

```
x = IO.read(path)
x.split(/\D+/).select {|n| n.to_i >= 0 && n.to_i < 32 && n.length < 3}.join("\n")
```

Comment: I believe this worked! This was a really smart way to do it and I didn't even think to use it like this. Thank you for helping and teaching me something!